# Making progress bar with button via JFrame

Tags: java, jframe, progress-bar, jprogressbar

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JButton button = new JButton("Compute!");
    JProgressBar bar = new JProgressBar(0, nOstudents);
    bar.setValue(0);
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    add(button);
    add(bar);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400, 300); 
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setTitle("sGen 2.0");
```

error message:

```
Generate.java:209: error: cannot find symbol
    add(button);
    ^
  symbol:   method add(JButton)
  location: class Generate
Generate.java:210: error: cannot find symbol
    add(bar);
    ^
  symbol:   method add(JProgressBar)
  location: class Generate
```

Basically Trying to make a button that starts a computation within the program and displays a progress bar. Under that code I have a method like this:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < nOstudents; i++) {
      bar.setValue(i+1);

     //do stuff
    }
  }
```

It takes quite a while to compute so I want a progress bar showing the progress. Anyways I'm not 100% sure if I'm using the progress bar the correct way and theirs a problem with the JFrame in general which I think I implemented wrong as I get the error message when trying to add things to the Frame

Comment: It should be `frame.add(component);` or you need to extend `JFrame` instead of creating `JFrame` object.

Comment: You need to do `frame.add(button)` and `frame.add(bar)` since you are declaring it as a variable.

Comment: If you want to mark the question solved, click the transparent tick next to the answer which best helped you solve it

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `button` and the `bar` to something.  Like

```
frame.add(button);
frame.add(bar);
```

or

```
Container panel = frame.getContentPane();
panel.add(button);
panel.add(bar);
```